# when to use Bpm and when to use esb

Tags: esb, business-process-management

I'm very new to this and a little confused. i need to connect a number of applications and put some intelligence in a central tool.
for example the first application send a push to a device and my solution wich be based on a bpm or esb will check if the device received the push, if not it will send an email. so here i think i have to use an esb because i need to connect my application with something else. Eventually I want to model this process so that the user of my application can view the progress of sending email. is that possible if i'm using esb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends which ESB you are using.

Some ESBs are very complicated to use, while others have a more visual, and flow based interface which would make your requirements easy to handle. A lot of ESBs are built with BPM tools as part of the package so you don't need choose between them.

We use Warewolf ESB which handles both of these very well.

Comment: is it free? actually i'm starting a project and i started with Mule esb community edition, I am afraid to hang later because the entreprise version is broader than the community one. and so that my client can follow the execution process that what i don't know if i can do it with an ESB.

Comment: Yes, free and open source - you're not limited to the "community edition" with less features.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need neither nor. And ESB allows you to integrate different technologies/protocols/dataformats in a losely coupled fashion so that your implementation does not need to know such details and you can replace the implementations later on, without having to change your service. BPM takes care of transactional long-running processes. The scenario you sketched does not seem to demand for either concept/technology.